# My dataframe converted to csv has two columns but PyCharm is only showing one. What might be wrong with PyCharm?

Tags: python, pandas, pycharm

```
import pandas

data = pandas.read_csv("2018_Central_Park_Squirrel_Census_-_Squirrel_Data.csv")
data_gray_count = len(data[data['Primary Fur Color'] == "Gray"])
data_red_count = len(data[data['Primary Fur Color'] == "Cinnamon"])
data_black_count = len(data[data['Primary Fur Color'] == "Black"])

data_dict = {
"Fur Color": ["Gray", "Cinamon","Black"],
    "Count": [data_gray_count,data_red_count,data_black_count],
}
df = pandas.DataFrame(data_dict)
df.to_csv("Squirrel_Count.csv")
```

[image]

CSV file has the column count but I'm not able to see in Pycharm

Comment: You converted the dict to dataframe , df = pandas.DataFrame(data_dict)

Comment: Can you `print` and check what's inside those variables `_count` and what does that df look like before `to_csv` ?

Comment: @Zircoz, The _Count actually prints the right count, when i open the CSV in finder it is actually in correct format but for some reason it doesn't show on Pycharm